# Variables globales o de sesion en laravel v.5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

estoy aprendiendo laravel y no tengo mucha experiencia y conocimiento en algunos conceptos, tengo una inquietud, me gustaría crear una variable que pueda ser accedida desde cualquier controlador de la aplicación.
he intentado manejarla de la siguiente manera, pero no ha funcionado por que en otro controlador que intento usarla me muestra el dato en blanco.

```
/*Definir*/
Session::set('CodClient', $cod_client); 
/*Obtener*/
Session::get('CodClient');
```

No me es posible manejarlo como CONSTANTES dado que esos valores no van a ser constantes, se definen cuando se ingresa a la ruta ("/") y carga el controlador inicial donde serán definidas esas variables

la version de laravel que estoy manejando es 5.3

Agradezco mucho su ayuda si necesitan mas detalles estoy al pendiente.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar [config](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/configuration#accessing-configuration-values), puedes declarar variables de configuración en tiempo de ejecución y acceder a ellas desde controladores o vista. Para guardar el valor:

```
config(['app.client_id' => $cod_client]);
```

Para acceder:

```
$valor = config('app.client_id');
```

Pero tengo curiosidad de por qué quieres manejar una variable global que es el id de un cliente de manera global, no es una buena práctica. De todas maneras, espero que eso te ayude.

Comment: Hola,  si es que son 3 variables la del código del cliente era ejemplo no hay problema pero hay otras dos que es un usuario y contraseña de una base de datos que no quiero se puedan ser visibles, dado que es un desarrollo que se esta haciendo con un web service y directamente en la aplicación no se están manejando modelos, pero el problema es que recibo esos datos en un controlador y defino la variable global y accedo a esa variable desde ese controlador y funciona de maravilla, pero cuando intento acceder a las mismas variables desde otro controlador no muestra nada. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear un provider y dentro del mismo declaras una función que sera la que uses de manera global tipo así:

```
    App::singleton('Nombre_variable_global', function(){
    $user=DB::table('users')->get();
    config(['app.all_users' => $user]);
    return $user;
    })};
```

Luego llamarlo así:
config('app.all_users') ó $usr=app('Nombre_variable_global');